# Open CV - Capture frame every X seconds while camera in use by Zoom or Skype/ Stream opencv captured frames to zoom meeting with Python

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I need to read a frame every 10 seconds for processing while I'm in a Zoom/Skype meeting in windows.
If I run Zoom (or any other app the uses the camera) I cannot capture frames using:

```
> import cv2
> 
> face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
> 
> cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

So I hoped that I either could stream to the meeting the captured frames from cv2.VideoCapture(0), or interrupt the zoom process for 1 frame every 10 seconds if possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: standard method is to create loop which read frames all time and process frame only every 10 second - and at the same time in this loop it can check keyboard and mouse events.

Comment: maybe make screenshots to get frames in Zoom. [Taking screenshots with OpenCV and Python](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/01/01/taking-screenshots-with-opencv-and-python/)

Comment: Didn't understand the first solution. Thought about the second solution but it might work only when zoom is in the foreground. Thus hoped for a different solution

Comment: in first moment I thought you mean zooming/rescaling image, not application "zoom".

Comment: it is not easy to get access to other program window and getting window which runs in background (or minimized) may be impossible.

Comment: @furas I could read the foreground window, and if it's zoom, screenshot it and analyze zoom. 
Is there a way to screenshot only zoom/skype app window?

Comment: It's indeed possible to open a webcam in opencv, process images, and then forward them to Zoom (not sure about skype). This can be done using [pyfakewebcam](https://github.com/jremmons/pyfakewebcam) and [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback). Check out this [blog post](https://elder.dev/posts/open-source-virtual-background/) for details.